# ruby datamapper breakdown of Serial vs String property for key

Tags: database-design, relational-database, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

Should every table have a Serial id? When would you need one, when wouldnt you? (associations, performance, etc?)

YouTube identifies videos with a key like "ttpYdIodMWc". I want something similar, but can't decide between id and identifier, or just a string key:

```
property :id, Serial, key: true
property :identifier, String, unique: true

# or

property :id, String, key: true
```

What is the suggested way for a SQL database, what about for NoSQL?

---

Some background - making a web app with Sinatra and DataMapper to support a Backbone client app.